# C# SQL Server to JSON with key groups

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've this table with is basically translations:

```
Key        CultureId     Txt
$HELLO     en-GB         Hello
$HELLO     pt-BR         Olá
$WELCOME   en-GB         Welcome
$WELCOME   pt-BR         Olá
```

And a select like:

```
Select Key, CultureId, Txt 
From Xlations 
Order by Key
```

This is an endpoint rest api, so I'd like a result like

```
{
   "$HELLO":{
      "en-GB":"Hello",
      "pt-BR":"Olá"
   },
   "$WELCOME":{
      "en-GB":"Bem Vindo",
      "pt-BR":"Welcome"
   }
}
```

So, keys with no arrays, totally in objects where the field key will be the parent of the assigned translations.

I know how to do it by creating few iterations on my code, but I was wondering if there is some shorthand for that because I don't want to keep my code huge and complex with iterates and nested iterates. Not sure if such things are possible, but: Anywone know some easy and simple way ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON output is usually generated using the `FOR JSON` clause. In your case, the required JSON output has variable key names, so `FOR JSON` is probably not an option. But, if the SQL Server version is 2017 or higher, you may try to generate the JSON manually, using string concatenation and aggregation. Also, as @Charlieface commented, escape the generated text with `STRING_ESCAPE()`.

Test table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Xlations
FROM (VALUES
   (N'$HELLO',   N'en-GB', N'Hello'),
   (N'$HELLO',   N'pt-BR', N'Olá'),
   (N'$WELCOME', N'en-GB', N'Welcome'),
   (N'$WELCOME', N'pt-BR', N'Bem Vindo')
) v ([Key], CultureId, Txt)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   N'{',
   STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'"', STRING_ESCAPE([Key], 'json'), N'":', [Value]), N','),
   N'}'
) AS Json
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT x.[Key], a.[Value]
   FROM Xlations x
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT CONCAT(
         N'{',
         STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'"', STRING_ESCAPE(CultureId, 'json'), N'":"', STRING_ESCAPE(Txt, 'json'), N'"'), N','),
         N'}'
      ) AS [Value]
      FROM Xlations
      WHERE [Key] = x.[Key]
   ) a
) t
```

Result:

```
{
   "$HELLO":{"en-GB":"Hello","pt-BR":"Olá"},
   "$WELCOME":{"en-GB":"Welcome","pt-BR":"Bem Vindo"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use your sql functions to do this and you have to do it manually.

```
SELECT CONCAT('{',string_agg(jsoncol,','),'}') Json
FROM
   (SELECT '1' AS col, CONCAT('"',[key],'"',':{' + string_agg(jsoncol,',') ,'}') AS jsoncol
    FROM 
       (SELECT [key],CONCAT('"',CultureId,'":"',txt ,'"') AS jsoncol FROM tb) t
    GROUP BY [key]) t
GROUP BY col
```

demo in [*dbfiddle<>uk*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92d4b6fe271f11636dc1b881869d35f0)

Comment: Don't forget `STRING_ESCAPE`

Answer (score 0):

[The answer given by @Zhorov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70004295/14868997) is good, but you can improve it by only querying the table once, aggregating then aggregating again.

This should be more performant than a correlated subquery.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
   N'{',
   STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'"', STRING_ESCAPE([Key], 'json'), N'":', [Value]), N','),
   N'}'
) AS Json
FROM (
   SELECT x.[Key], CONCAT(
         N'{',
         STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'"', STRING_ESCAPE(CultureId, 'json'), N'":"', STRING_ESCAPE(Txt, 'json'), N'"'), N','),
         N'}'
      ) AS [Value]
   FROM Xlations x
   GROUP BY x.[Key]
) t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbaff1915936c37f7b43672e02b3f714)